# StackOverflowException trying to return a Linq query result as a List through a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, entity-framework

I have had a lot of problems with this stuff and I can't solve it even with a simpler example.

I've a WCF service that returns a list of objects (from my Entity Model).

The model only has 2 tables:
Person, with id, name and office_id (foreign key)
and Office, with id and address

I'm making a really simple linq query that returns the first of these people. This is working ok, even the "ToList()" method works ok.

The problem is that when I try to return it through the service it crashes with a "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I think it's related to the Navigation Properties when it tries to serialize the Person object. These Navigation Properties appear in both the Person and Office model, the Person table has a "Office" Navigation Property, but Office table has a "Person" Navigation Property too!!

I think these navigation properties can be useful for other scenarios but I can't find a way to say not to load those contents or at least not to serialize and return it through the service!!

This is the linq query (this works, the list really has one person inside):

```
var query = (from chosen in entities.person
            select chosen).First<person>();

return query.ToList<person>();
```

Does anybody has ever seen something like this? I have had several WCF-Linq projects before and I never had any similar issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it setting both ProxyCreationEnabled and LazyLoadingEnabled as false in the entities object:

```
Model.Entities entities = new Model.Entities();

        public ServicePeople()
        {
            entities.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            entities.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a circular reference problem, try decorating your Person and Office class with:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll search how to decorate an autogenerated Entity from the database (if this is possible ;-))

Comment: One question, how can it be a circular reference if the only relation between both tables is only that Person has as Foreign Key the primary key of Office??

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. I was asking why the model created the Office to Person navigation property if it is not set in the database :-S

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your WCF service uses the default `DataContractSerializer`, try decorating the navigation properties with [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll search how to decorate each property in a Entity autogenerated from the database (if this is possible ;-))